# Line of code causes crash in instruments but not in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, crash, loops, instruments

```
BOOL continueLoop;
CGPoint thePoint;   

while(continueLoop != NO)
{
    continueLoop = NO;

    thePoint = [self generateRandomLocation];

    NSMutableArray *blocks = [self getBlocksForX:thePoint.x];

    for(BlueBlock *block in blocks)
    {
        if(block.getBlockLocationY == thePoint.y)
        {
            continueLoop = YES;
        }
    }
    [blocks release];
}
```

This causes a crash when ran in instruments but not in Xcode. I narrowed the problem down, it happens when this line of code is in a loop... NSMutableArray *blocks = [self getBlocksForX: thePoint.x]; the method returns a NSMutableArray, I store it in blocks each time the loop is executed then at the end of the loop I release it. What would be causing instruments to crash?

Answer (score 3):

since you never `alloc`, `copy`, or `retain` blocks you should not be releasing it.

It may help for errors like this to run the static analyzer.

Comment: the method returns an allocated NSMutableArray

Comment: ah, usual convention is (from memory management programming guide) `You “create” an object using a method whose name begins with “alloc” or “new” or contains “copy”` http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-BEHDEDDB

Comment: Sorry for triple post, I changed it from a while loop to a do while loop (tried everything else I could think of already)and problem solved.

Comment: the problem with the while loop is (maybe) that you don't initialize continueLoop